# Coding Meetup #9 - Higher-Order Functions Series - Is the meetup age-diverse? (Python) Pandas solution?

Tags: python, pandas

I've completed the aforementioned kata on CodeWars and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution using pandas?
I was thinking about using `pd.Series.between()` but couldn't quite get to a solution.

Here is the CodeWars Kata prompt:

> You will be given an array of objects (associative arrays in PHP)
> representing data about developers who have signed up to attend the
> next coding meetup that you are organising.
>
> Your task is to return:
>
> true if developers from all of the following age groups have signed
> up: teens, twenties, thirties, forties, fifties, sixties, seventies,
> eighties, nineties, centenarian (at least 100 years young). false
> otherwise. For example, given the following input array:
>
> ```
> list1 = [
>   { 'firstName': 'Harry', 'lastName': 'K.', 'country': 'Brazil', 'continent': 'Americas', 'age': 19, 'language': 'Python' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Kseniya', 'lastName': 'T.', 'country': 'Belarus', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 29, 'language': 'JavaScript'},
>   { 'firstName': 'Jing', 'lastName': 'X.', 'country': 'China', 'continent': 'Asia', 'age': 39, 'language': 'Ruby' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Noa', 'lastName': 'A.', 'country': 'Israel', 'continent': 'Asia', 'age': 40, 'language': 'Ruby' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Andrei', 'lastName': 'E.', 'country': 'Romania', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 59, 'language': 'C' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Maria', 'lastName': 'S.', 'country': 'Peru', 'continent': 'Americas', 'age': 60, 'language': 'C' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Lukas', 'lastName': 'X.', 'country': 'Croatia', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 75, 'language': 'Python' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Chloe', 'lastName': 'K.', 'country': 'Guernsey', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 88, 'language': 'Ruby' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Viktoria', 'lastName': 'W.', 'country': 'Bulgaria', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 98, 'language': 'PHP' },
>   { 'firstName': 'Piotr', 'lastName': 'B.', 'country': 'Poland', 'continent': 'Europe', 'age': 128, 'language': 'JavaScript' }
> ]
> ```
>
> your function should return true as there is at least one developer from each age group.
>
> Notes:
>
> The input array will always be valid and formatted as in the example
> above. Age is represented by a number which can be any positive
> integer up to 199.

And this is what I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
def is_age_diverse(lst): 
    ages_list = [i for i in range(10, 101, 10)]
    for i in pd.DataFrame(lst)['age']:
        for j in ages_list:
            if j <= i < (j + 10):
                ages_list.remove(j)
            elif i > 110 and 100 in ages_list:
                ages_list.remove(100)
    return not ages_list
```

I looked through the other solutions on the page but I found nobody using Pandas for this.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Also if you have any suggestions how I could improve upon my existing code apart from Pandas, just hit me with it.

Comment: `pd.cut` might help here with its `bins` and `labels` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.cut()` and the `groupby` function, and assuming `ages` is a series of the age values (or possibly a dataframe with a single column), you can achieve it with:

```
bins = list(range(10, 101, 10))+[200]
ages.groupby(pd.cut(ages, bins, right = False, include_lowest = False)).count().all()
```

Note that `bins` is built using the assumption that the largest value is 199. From the question description you might want to change the lowest value from 10 to 13 since that is where I would start "teens", but I followed the logic in the code from the post.

The `count` function at the end will aggregate the count of each bin, and `all` returns true if all values are non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses `pandas` and `groupby` -- we groupby age category and make sure we have exactly 10 of them

```
import pandas as pd
def is_age_diverse(lst): 
    def age_category(age):
        if age >= 100:
            return 10
        return age//10
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
    return len(df[df['age']>=10].set_index('age').groupby(age_category).first())==10
```